# Why do Jacoco excludes java classes?

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, continuous-integration, jacoco

I'm running the command `mvn sonar:sonar`.

Here's the output from Jenkins:

```
[JaCoCo plugin] Source Inclusions: **/*.java
[JaCoCo plugin] Source Exclusions: 
[JaCoCo plugin] - <PATH>/workspace/<MODULE1>/src/main/java 10 files
[JaCoCo plugin] - <PATH>/workspace/<MODULE2>/src/main/java 1 files
[JaCoCo plugin] - <PATH>/workspace/<MODULE3>/src/main/java 65 files
[JaCoCo plugin] - <PATH>/workspace/<MODULE4>/src/main/java 5 files
[JaCoCo plugin] - <PATH>/workspace/<MODULE5>/src/main/java 64 files
```

Why do the Jacoco plugin exclude these java files?

I don't have any `<exclude>` tag in my `jacoco-maven-plugin` configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's the output from Jenkins:
>
> ```
> [JaCoCo plugin] Source Inclusions: **/*.java
> [JaCoCo plugin] Source Exclusions: 
> [JaCoCo plugin] - <PATH>/workspace/<MODULE1>/src/main/java 10 files
> ```
>
> Why do the Jacoco plugin exclude these java files?
>
> I don't have any `<exclude>` tag in my `jacoco-maven-plugin` configuration

These [messages produced by **Jenkins** Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/blob/jacoco-3.0.4/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/jacoco/JacocoPublisher.java#L631-L632), which has its own configuration unrelated to configuration of `jacoco-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Anyways, it's weird since I don't have any exclusions in the jenkins's jacoco plugin (the field is empty)