# How to exclude builder classes from Jacoco code coverage in Jenkins?

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco

My classes have @builder annotation and in Jacoco code coverage in Jenkins it's creating classname$builder class and it's showing 0% or very less for code coverage. How to ignore those classes in Jenkins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude package from Jacoco coverage in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883900/exclude-package-from-jacoco-coverage-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

You could use exclude tag provided by jacoco. Assuming you are using maven you can do the following

```
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*builder**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
```

For more details, check the jacoco [report documentation](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html)

Comment: Jenkins plugin doesn't use `excludes` configuration of `jacoco-maven-plugin` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279463/why-do-jacoco-excludes-java-classes

Comment: <excludes>
   <exclude>
   ....
   </exclude>
</excludes>


not working in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me. No pom changes were required.

Create a file named **lombok.config** in your directory’s root (where pom is located) and set the following flag in the file:

**lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true**